# Error when trying to copy directory recusivly using an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a folder structure that looks like this on a unix machine that is created by earlier parts of the playbook:

```
program
  -bin
  -conf
  -scripts
  -extraction
    -resources
      -conf
        -- directories, files, etc
      -scripts
        -- directories, files, etc
```

And I want to copy the contents of `program/extraction/resources/conf` into `program/conf` and the contents of `program/extraction/resources/scripts` into `program/scripts`

But when I try to use ansible to perform the copy like this:

```
- name: Copy config to config location
  copy:
    src: "{{ deployment_path }}/program/extraction/resources/conf/"
    dest: "{{ deployment_path }}/program/conf/"
    mode: 0644
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ username }}"
  any_errors_fatal: True
```

Then I get an error like this:

```
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find '/path/to/program/extraction/resources/conf/' in expected paths."}
```

But if I run `ll /path/to/program/extraction/resources/conf/` then I see the files, so I know that the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`copy:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html) is for control machine to managed machine, although the [`remote_src: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-remote_src) will cause it to behave more like what you're expecting

Be forewarned that the `copy` task has a lot of caveats in the fine manual, which you'll want to be aware of; you may be much happier with the old fashion `cp -R` or its `rsync` friend